# How to grant access to a folder after authentication in nodejs with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, basic-authentication

I am new to nodejs and I have been looking for a solution quite a while now and none solves my specific problem unfortunately. Or at least I just don't get it.

In my nodejs project I am using a public folder where all my html and js files are stored.

In server.js, which is outside of the public folder I do:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

A specific user, let's call him Tom, will access tom-page.html.
Another user, let's call him Fred, will access fred-page.html. 
These files and their scripts (javascript) are all in that public folder.

Now what I am trying to do is to protect the public folder with a static password. If Tom logs in, then he should be redirected to /public/tom-page.html and for Fred it should be /public/fred-page.html. And they should have access to all the other files in that folder.

What I did so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var is_tom = false;

var auth = function(req, res, next) {
  function unauthorized(res) {
    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
    return res.send(401);
  };

  var user = basicAuth(req);

  if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
    return unauthorized(res);
  };

  if (user.name === 'fred' && user.pass === 'fred-pwd') {
    is_tom = false;
    return next();
  } else if (user.name === 'tom' && user.pass === 'tom-pwd') {
    is_tom = true;
    return next();
  } else {
    return unauthorized(res);
  }
};

const http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', auth, function(req, res) {
  if (is_tom) {
    res.send('hi tom');
  } else {
    res.send('hi fred');
  }
});
```

This works. But I don't know how to grant them access to the public folder aka `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and also redirect them to their page.

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 4):

I've just found a solution that works:

```
app.use(auth, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I've just put auth before specifying the the static folder that I am using.
Does anyone else have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the pages in the folder WEB-INF, this directory is only accessible for your application. If the user is logged in, you can send it to the file inside that folder.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get basic-auth to show a html form instead of a popup? Do you know? thx

Comment: You can use session for register if user are logged. If he are are logged, redirect he for archive in WEB-INF. I do not know how you do for redirect.